# Initialize hashmap with values in vyper

Tags: python, vyper

When using hashmaps in Vyper, can we initialize it directly with more than one value?

I am currently looping over a separate list of addresses in the constructor.

```
allowedAdmins: HashMap[address, bool]
allowedAdminsList: address[3] = [0xADD1E55E11, 0xADD2E55E22, 0xADD3E55E33]

@external
def __init__():
    for _admin in self.allowedAdminsList:
        self.allowedAdmins[_admin] = True
```

But is it possible to just initialize it in a single line if possible. Something like

```
allowedAdmins: HashMap[address, bool] = [(0xADD1E55E11, True),
                                         (0xADD2E55E22, True),
                                         (0xADD3E55E33, True)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to initialize storage variables in vyper. In this case you can initialize in `__init__()` function the hashmap and when you try to deploy the smart contract for the first time this function'll initialize the hashmap with your values.

The documentation say this:

> For storage variables (declared in the module scope), an initial value
> cannot be set

More information [here](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scoping-and-declarations.html).